# 2-dimension table and NullPointerException

Tags: java

I have a problem with this piece of code:

```
PointerCoords[][]srodki = new PointerCoords[n2][];

for(int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
{
        srodki[i] = new PointerCoords[n2];
}

for(int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
{
        for(int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        {
                srodki[i][j].y = r + j*k;
                srodki[i][j].x = r + i*k;
        }

}
```

Why do I get a NullPointerException?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't initialize the content of
`srodki[i][j]` before performing the insertion:

```
srodki[i][j].y = r + j*k;
srodki[i][j].x = r + i*k;
```

So first, you need to perform:

```
srodki[i][j] = new PointerCoords();
```

and then it shall be ok.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you don't initialize objects in the array.
Initially, all the array elements are `null` unless you initialize them explicitly like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
    {
            for(int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
            {
                    // your constructor goes here
                    srodki[i][j] = new PointerCoords();
                    srodki[i][j].y = r + j*k;
                    srodki[i][j].x = r + i*k;
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you haven't **initialized** the *references*.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your array as follows:

```
PointerCoords[][] srodki = new PointerCoords[n2][n2];
for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
    srodki[i] = new PointerCoords[n2];
    for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
       srodki[i][j] = new PointerCoords();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you are initializing your array, it contains an n2 * n2 matrix of null values.

In order to actually be able to set a property of a `PointerCoords` object inside the array, you must first do

```
array[i][j] = new PointerCoords();
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct way of doing to avoid null pointer is

```
PointerCoords[][]srodki = new PointerCoords[n2][];

    for(int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
    {
            srodki[i] = new PointerCoords[n2];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
    {
            for(int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
            {
                    srodki[i][j]= new PointerCoords(); // added line
                    srodki[i][j].y = r + j*k;
                    srodki[i][j].x = r + i*k;
            }

    }
```

Comment: Redundant loop with `i` index

Comment: I have just corrected the null pointer exception, not the overall logic